# parsing csv issue getting two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have this csv file:

```
id,...MANY FIELDS,Gold
,020-008,20008,...MANY FIELDS...,34.5,21.49
```

for some reason im receiving the last element as two arrays:

```
    ....
    [24] => 2
)
Array
(
    [0] => 149
)
```

This is the code I'm using...

```
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        print_r($data);
```

i really dont understand why this is happening...

Comment: ***...MANY FIELDS...*** - set the buffer size higher `fgetcsv` uses. http://php.net/fgetcsv - e.g. 4096 instead of 1000. then try again. (in your case technically 1004 should suffice, but then you might see the error soon again, so give it some more space)